# What is the translation of 托业考试必备 ?

Tags: translation, grammar, syntax

I ve looked up the words:

- 托 = to entrust (only one possible meaning, i do not know which one makes   sense)
- 业 = enterprise
- 考试 = test
- 必备 = essential

I can make no sense of this sentence, i even can not analyze its parts of speeches.

Could you explain the contained in this sentence?

Comment: 托业 = TOEIC. Does it make sense to you now?

Comment: yes,indeed, it makes now much more sense, so tuoye is actually a noun, i guess the meaning is: 
essentials for toeic test, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. ///

Answer (score 3):

I do not agree with S.Rhee. It seems like here it is a name of a book or some TOEIC test preparation reference. Thus, the better translation in English would be:

*Essential for TOEIC*

Comment: *TOEIC Essentials* would work too.

Answer (score 0):

use iciba：（托业）TOEIC exam required

Comment: If 托业 was not used as a fixed term, would its verbatim translation be: "to support buisness" ?

Comment: in above question 必备 apparently is used as predicate，web also shows instances of attributive use in the context of TOEIC，e。g。
摘要：本系列文章整理出托业考试（TOEIC）必备词汇，希望对备考托业考试的网友有所帮助。
对考生而言，《托业考试官方指南》是备考TOEIC的必备参考用书之一

Comment: @meireikei It _is_ a fixed term. That's like asking "if 北大 wasn't a fixed term, would it mean North-big?".